# Namespace not appearing even after adding Reference of class Library Project in VS2013 :: All The Projects in solution targeting 4.5.1 .Net framework

Tags: namespaces

I am working on MVC5 project in VS2013 , I have class library project named  as ProductEntities, I added ProductEntities.dll reference

[image]

In another project named as  JustShopServices, reference was added but namespace in the Service1.cs files not appearing in JustShopServices project.

All the projects in solution are targeting 4.5.1, Not able to understand.
I am stuck. Can anybody help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you add a dll as a reference, you get access to the *classes* in it, not the *files*.  Make sure the classes you're looking for are `public`.

Comment: Thanks richie, the problem was i didnt have any single file present in that project , hense even if dll is added my service was not recognizing the namespace. means if no class files are present in lib project then even after adding its reference , its namespace is not recognized.. at lease one class file should be present in lib project.